# DriveApp conversion from Google Sheet to PDF now fails

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

Volunteers to the charity are asked to fill in an application form (a google form). When they submit it the following script runs. Basically it copies the last line of the input spreadsheet to a new spreadsheet (using a copy of a master spreadsheet which has all the correct formatting)  and then saves that new spreadsheet as a PDF.

The PDF save has suddenly stopped working (it's been running for about a year) and now simply creates a blank PDF.

Can someone please explain what I need to do to get it working again?

```
//This section copies the last completed row to a new spreadsheet, using a copy of the master sheet, saves as a PDF and cleans up     
//Create an input array to hold the last row data
    var inputArray = [];
//Copy the responses into an array
  for (i=1;i <=48;i++) {
    inputArray[i] = inputSheet.getRange(lastRowInput, i, 1, 1).getValue();
  }

//Get some info from the SysAdmin sheet which contains the IDs of the folder, master app form and demographics sheet  
var sysAdminSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("SysAdmin")
var folderID = sysAdminSheet.getRange("B1").getValue();
var masterCopy = sysAdminSheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
var demoSheetID = sysAdminSheet.getRange("B3").getValue();
var nokSheetID = sysAdminSheet.getRange("B4").getValue();
var medSheetID = sysAdminSheet.getRange("B5").getValue();

//Because the data will be loaded into picklists we need to manipulate the answer to the disability q to fit.
  var tempDis = inputArray[47];
  switch (tempDis) {
    case "Specific learning disability (such as dyslexia or dyspraxia)":
      inputArray[47] = "Specific learning disability";
      break;
    case "General learning disability (such as Down's syndrome)":
      inputArray[47] = "General learning disability";
      break;
    case "Cognitive impairment (such as autistic spectrum disorder or resulting from head injury)":
      inputArray[47] = "Cognitive impairment";
      break;
    case "Long-standing illness or health condition (such as cancer, HIV, diabetes, chronic heart disease, or epilepsy)":
      inputArray[47] = "Long-standing illness or health condition";
      break;
    case "Mental health condition (such as depression or schizophrenia)":
      inputArray[47] = "Mental health condition";
      break;
    case "Physical impairment or mobility issues (such as difficulty using arms or using a wheelchair or crutches)":
      inputArray[47] = "Physical impairment or mobility issues";
      break;
  }


//Copy the spreadsheet containing the master form into a new spreadsheet, name it with the email address and get it's id
//inputArray[2] contains the email address, which is used as the spreadsheet name
var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);  
var newSheet = DriveApp.getFileById(masterCopy).makeCopy(inputArray[2], destFolder).getId();

// Open the new sheet and assign it to the outputSheet var
var outputSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newSheet);
//Copy the info into the outputsheet. Because it has 'section headers' (See row 18 for an example) we can't just do a straight copy
  for (i=2;i<=17;i++) {
    outputSheet.getRange("B" + i).setValue(inputArray[i]);
  }
//Referee info  
  for (i=19; i<=31;i++) {
    outputSheet.getRange("B" + i).setValue(inputArray[i-1]);
  }
//NoK info
  for (i=32;i<=41;i++) {
    outputSheet.getRange("B" + i).setValue(inputArray[i-2])
  }
//Confidentiality question is the only one in this section
  outputSheet.getRange("B42").setValue(inputArray[39]);
//As above for the rehab of offenders question
  outputSheet.getRange("B44").setValue(inputArray[40]);
//And the Equal opps questions
  for (i=46;i<=53;i++) {
    outputSheet.getRange("B" + i).setValue(inputArray[i-5]);
  }
//This is the bit that isn't working
//Save the file as a PDF

var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(outputSheet.getId());
var theBlob = pdf.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(inputArray[2]);
destFolder.createFile(theBlob);
```

Comment: Is your spreadsheet document that you export as PDF correctly filled ? Or is also blank ?

Comment: Spreadsheet is filled correctly

Comment: What happens when you change `"application/PDF"` to the `MimeType` constant for PDF? i.e. type `MimeType.` and select the correct value from the autocomplete options.

Comment: Hi @tehhowch I tried changing the line to var theBlob = pdf.getBlob().setName(inputArray[2]).getAs(MimeType.PDF);  and it creates a PDF, but still empty. Not sure if I've got the format of the code right? I wrote the original script but I'm not a developer

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was intending. Looks like you can also drop the first `getBlob` call, i.e. `pdf.getAs(MimeType.PDF)` is the same as `pdf.getBlob().getAs(MimeType.PDF)`. Do you encounter this same issue on other spreadsheets, or only this sheet? Have there been new contents added to this spreadsheet recently?

Comment: Hi @tehhowch made the changes you suggested but still get the same result, a blank PDF. There have been no changes to the spreadsheet format or questions recently, just new volunteers being added as they complete the application form. We don't use this function (converting to PDF) anywhere else. I will setup a test version and report back

Comment: I tried creating a new worksheet and copied the script into it. Populated with 1 input line and ran again with exactly the same result.

Comment: Resolved it by adding a SpreadsheetApp.flush(); command before the PDF create to ensure all the spreadsheet changes were committed.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by adding a SpreadsheetApp.flush(); command before the PDF create to ensure all the spreadsheet changes were committed.